# Can anybody push to my project on github?

Tags: git, github, push

I set up a repository on GitHub, and I can push local stuff to this remote repository. Can anybody change my repository on GitHub freely? Or if I push something to Linux kernel, are the changes I made added to it and public for all?

Comment: If you're using public repo - evferyone can see but NOT modify until you make him collaborator.

Answer (score 112):

No, all repositories are read-only for anonymous users. 
By default only the owner of the repository has write access. If you can push to your own repo, it's because you are using one of the supported authentification methods (HTTPS, SSH, ...).

If you want to grant someone else privileges to push to your repo, you would need to configure that access in the project settings.

To contribute to projects in which you don't have push access, you push to your own copy of the repo, then ask for a pull-request. Linux is not a good example for that, because the kernel developers do not use GitHub pull requests.

Comment: Then how does GPG secures the commis? as nobody else can commit to our repo?

Answer (score 49):

Nobody can push directly to your repository if you are not already granting them write access.

The process for contributing to a public repository in GitHub starts by forking the repository, then **pushing the change onto the forked**, then creating a **pull request onto the original repository**. After that comes the role of the project owner to review and take action (merge/decline) of the requested code change.

For more details, please check the below helpful article:

https://akrabat.com/the-beginners-guide-to-contributing-to-a-github-project

Answer (score 46):

No, but if the repository is public others can fork it, commit to their own fork.

They can then ask you to pull some of the changes in their fork into your repository via a pull-request.