# How to make a DISTRIBUTED repository on my own server

Tags: git, github

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17443115/4451521) when you have a github repository, only you can push to the repo (of course others can clone it and push to their own repository but that is not the theme of this question)

I believe this is called **distributed model**. Anyway, my question is, without using github (or other) how can I make a repository like this in my own network using git? Is this possible?

Important EDIT:

First I want to thanks jxpp for his answer. And I want to prevent this question be misunderstood and marked as "possible duplicate" (as it has been done) *without reading the question*

Let me stress the word **DISTRIBUTED MODEL**. 
I already know how to make a centralized repository (with bare) as jxpp kindly wrote. What I want to achieve is a distributed model similar to the one used in github. I will explain what is a distributed model here.

In a distributed model, you have a repository (same as in a centralized one) and you can fetch and push there. However other users *cannot* push to that repository. They can only fetch from there. 
What other users can do is to clone that repo and push their own changes and commits to that cloned repository. Then later they can ask for their changes to be incorporated to the first main repository in which case you *and only you* can decide to merge those changes to the main repository. That -I believe- is how github works and I want to reproduce that in my own server.

Comment: @phd I read the "possible duplicate". This question is so past that. I already know how to create a repository. My question clearly said "distributed model"

Comment: I read the questions in the search too. None address this issue

Answer (score 1):

Run `git init --bare` in a folder to create a bare repo. This is a special kind of repo that doesn't have any working copy of the repo's files and can be used to push to and pull from by many users.

You can work with it in the same way you interact with github (or similar) repos. You add it as a remote and then you and anyone else with access to it can utilize it.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to make it clearer what I want to achieve

Comment: @KansaiRobot I read your edit. What you want can be achieved with a bare repo, where you limit other people's access via ssh keys and file permissions, and achieve the behaviour you want via hooks.